# Export glTF 2.0 with shading

Tags: shaders, export, gltf

I have shading set up to have a glitter effect. But I need to show it in AR (arguement reality). While I'm exporting to .usd or .gltf/glb it doesn't show effect I created, only black material.

[image]

Do you know if there's a way to do that without changing extension?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Most Blender nodes cannot be exported from Blender. To create a material compatible with export, you'll need to 'bake' the nodes into textures, connected to inputs on the Principled BSDF material. The glTF addon documentation goes into more detail on supported materials: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html